# ModelAttributeMethodProcessor cannot resolve arguments

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 methods with such request mapping

1. `@RequestMapping(value = "/page/{page}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})`
2. `@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}/{subCategory}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})`

when i go to url '/page/smth' spring can not resolve which method should be called and i get

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:110)
```

How can I 'help' spring resolve this problem? Maybe there are some configuration?

Comment: You might want to post what you are doing in Controller methods, and the complete error log. Most likely you are missing binding between your UI and Spring backend.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? `page/smth` request should resolve to `"/page/{page}"`.